# AngularFire and Firestore - Querying collection once whilst navigating components

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying reduce the reads performed against my firestore database. In a small demo, I have two components.

**Component 1**

Component 1 is a list of artists stored in the firestore collection `company/artists`

**Component 2**

Component 2 is a list of albums from any artist stored in the firestore collection `company/albums`

I connect an artist to an album by having the `artist_id` listed in each album document.

I have a service that’s referenced in a component. The service contains an angularfire collection query which i initiate within the service constructor. I put a console log inside the query function to log when the function is called. I essentially want the albums query to only happen once, even when I navigate back a to the artists component and return, I don’t want it to fire again. If I new item is added to the list, I'd like that to sync, which it does.

However, right now even though the `console.log('get all items called');` is only fired once as i navigate through the components, the `console.log('data = ', data)` is fired every time I go to the albums component, which makes me think that I am indeed querying the database everytime.

**Questions**

1. How do i make sure that this query is only run once?
2. How do I achieve question 1, but also sync any new changes to the list from the database?
3. Or have I actually done it correctly?

**Albums Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlbumItemsService } from '../services/category-items.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-album-items',
   templateUrl: './album-items.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./album-items.component.css']
 })

export class AlbumItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public albumItemsService: AlbumItemsService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AlbumItemsService {

   private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
   items: Observable<any[]>;

   constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
     console.log('Album Item Service Called')
     this.getAllItems();
   }

   getAllItems(){
      console.log('get all items called');
      this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('url');
      this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
         map(actions => actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data();
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         console.log('data = ', data)
         return { id, ...data };
      }))
  );
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of AlbumItemsService.items | async">
    {{ item.item_title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I messed around with the native firestore code instead of angularfire.

```
this.db.collection("collection").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    var cities = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        cities.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log("cities = ", cities);
});
```

This *seems* like it doesn't query the database everytime. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking mainly in your "UPDATE". If you want to query collection you should use `.get` instead of `.onSnapshot` the reference can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#get).

Comment: Thanks @vitooh. What's the difference between the two? I essentially want to run a query against a collection once in a service, as it'll be used by many components whilst navigating around. I just don't want it firing multiple times.

Comment: `.onSnapshot` attaches a listener for QuerySnapshot events while `get` executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot. So if you need to do snapshot once it seems more reasonable.